# Need to listen to iTunes track and piano for learning

Tags: piano, self-learning

I am learning piano and thought that if I play the lesson track into my headphones at the same time as the piano output I could practice timing better, and for the pieces I need to learn for the exam I can get the timing perfect. What sort of equipment do I need?

Comment: I would suggest a mixer with at least two stereo channels and a headphone output. You'll also need leads to connect the piano & music player outputs to the mixer inputs. (I can't recommend a specific model.)

Comment: what are the outputs on your piano (1/4" stereo?), your music player (3.5mm stereo?) and what style of input is your headphones ( 3.5mm stereo?). Does your piano have an input?

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of pratice you don't need a perfect studio mix, you may not need anything more than your music player and in-ear headphones  (preferably not of the tight earplug type). Just put the phones (or even just a single one) in your ear(s) and regulate volume so that you can confortably hear  the "backing track" with just enough volume to let you follow the timing while normally playing your piano.

Comment: I have to say, though, that although this kind of practice may be useful, up to a point, in my opinion it will be detrimental if you take it too far. If you just mechanically follow somebody else's performance you will have a mechanical performance yourself. You need to develop your own sense of timing and of "phrase as unity"  and it's unlikely you achieve that by metronome or "back track" practice alone.